# How to write a cycle to change the date

Tags: r, parsing

```
library(rvest)

webpage <- read_html("https://rsport.ria.ru/services/football/more.html?id=1794916111&date=20220612T164700") 
results <- webpage %>% html_nodes(".list-item__title") %>% html_attr("href")
```

I recently started learning R and parsing and I need to collect news from these pages, I understand that I need to write a loop to change the date in the address bar, but I don't understand how

Comment: How about the time, does it have to be the exact time every day T=16:47:00?

Comment: No, i need to download the news, for 24 hours, for example 06/12/22, time does not play a role.

Comment: but at the same time, I think you need a cycle so that the date changes, or some other way to download a lot of links @user16087142

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that time does not really play a role
I suggest you pass a date in a variable and then give it as.character to format it as a plain number.

see the code below.

```
    #Passing a date in a variable
    newbies<- as.character(Sys.Date()-1, format = "%Y%m%d")

then using the glue package you can pass the variable along where the date is meant to be in the link.
see code below

    webpage <- read_html(glue::glue("https://rsport.ria.ru/services/football/more.html?id=1794916111&date={newbies}"))
```

Try this

Comment: I didn’t understand very much how it will automatically change the date, for example, from 20220612 to 20220613, you may need to add the code, but since I started doing this recently, I don’t understand, sorry, if you can show me more :)

Comment: in your R studio, there is a function that display date eg
Sys.Date(), this function will today's date.
for example, if you want yesterday's date then the function will be written like this 
Sys.Date()-1 which means that the system should minus today's date which will give you the date of yesterday, if you want the last two days the Sys.Date()-2, if you want last 3 days then Sys.Date()-3, depending on the date you want.

Comment: so in your case, since the date in the link is formatted as a plain number eg 20220612
that's why I'm using this script to format Sys.Date-1 as.character see below.
newbies<- as.character(Sys.Date()-1, format = "%Y%m%d"

Comment: There is a package called glue
install it. 
it is used to join strings together in r
so I used it to join your the variable that I pass to "newbies"
webpage <- read_html(glue::glue("https://rsport.ria.ru/services/football/more.html?id=1794916111&date={newbies}"))
Please try it lets see that it is working